# Why 16bit to 8bit conversion produces striped image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am testing a segmentation algorithm on several VHSR satellite images, which originally comes in 16bit format, but when I convert them to 8bit images, the produced images are showing striped appearance. 
I've been trying different python libraries (skimage, cv2, scipy) getting similar results.

1) The original 16-bit image it is a 4 band image (NIR,B,G,R), so you need to choose the right bands to create a true color image, RGB image (4,3,2 bands). thanks in advance. It can be downloaded from this link:
[16bit image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjbhuqesqsvj84d/SkySat_16bit.tif?dl=0)

2) I use this code to convert each pixel value, from a 16-bit integer now fitting within 8-bit range:

```
  from scipy.misc import bytescale
  SS = io.imread('Imag16bit.tif')
  SS = bytescale(SS)
  SS = np.asarray(SS) 
  plt.imshow(SS)
```

This is my result of above code:

[image]

Comment: My suggestion would be to share the image, your code and the result.

Comment: Hi @Mark_Setchell, I share my code, but I dont know how to share images here, could you explain me how to upload images here. Thanks in advance, Jaime

Comment: If your image is not in a format acceptable to StackOverflow, you can upload it to any file sharing service or website and then click the "chain link" icon in the formatting toolbar after **Bold** and *Italic* and to the left of the double quotes and add a link to the file you have uploaded elsewhere.

Comment: @JaimeLopez check the edit and add those missing details. Then it'll be faster to help your issue. The slight "angle" effect can be caused by incorrect width or height of target (output) canvas when setting pixels as sampled from source (input).

Comment: The white balance is screwed up as well, indicating that each plane has a different min/max that is scaled against. Likely the min/max are computed for each image row separately instead of for the whole array. Try specifying the min and max in the call to `bytescale`.

Comment: Is it 16-bits for total color of one pixel or 16-bits for each color channel within one pixel?... What's the point of going 8-bit for your segmentation algorithm? Is greyscaling or posterization not a worthy alternative? I can't explain the stripes but your first (before) image scales down to 417x187 but your converted (after) image is 417x183, a small difference but it hints something is missing somewhere thus corrupting the output.

Comment: Your 16-bit image is an 8-bit JPEG!

Comment: I add a link to download original 16-bit image, in response to those who asked for it. @MarkSetchell

Comment: @Cris_Luengo I corrected the link, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

`bytescale` works for me. I think the `asarray` step messes up something.

```
import cv2
from skimage import io
from scipy.misc import bytescale

image = io.imread('SkySat_16bit.tif')
cv2.imshow('Original', image)
print(image.dtype)

image = bytescale(image)
print(image.dtype)

cv2.imshow('Converted', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, earlier I up-voted too soon. There is no point testing with `r4DQe.jpg`. We need a link of the original 16-bit TIF file, since JPG is 24-bit (8-bits per colour channel) it gives misleading results.

Comment: You have a point. @Jaime please provide a link with the 16-Bit TIF file.

Comment: I added a link to original 16-bit image now, it is a 4 band image (NIR,B,G,R), so you need to choose the right bands to create a true color image, RGB image (4,3,2 bands). thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @parthagar, sorry for delay, I think as you said, the asarray step I was using maybe is the cause to get that striped image. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it a lot. Jaime

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a way to do it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image
from tifffile import imsave, imread

# Load image
im = imread('SkySat_16bit.tif')

# Extract Red, Green and Blue bands into separate 8-bit arrays
R = (im[:,:,3]/256).astype(np.uint8)
G = (im[:,:,2]/256).astype(np.uint8)
B = (im[:,:,1]/256).astype(np.uint8)

# Combine bands into RGB array
RGB = np.dstack((R,G,B))

# Save to disk
Image.fromarray(RGB).save('result.png')
```

[image]

You may want to adjust the contrast a bit, and check I selected the correct bands.

Comment: Hi @Mark_Setchell, sorry for delay, following your steps I got same image as you, a bit dark image, but without stripes. Thanks, Jaime